# Workflow for developing and publishing a Foundation template with Hugo and GitHub pages?

Tags: zurb-foundation, github-pages, hugo

I'm creating a website which shall be hosted on GitHub Pages using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io) as a static site generator.

The Hugo theme itself is being developed using the Zurb template of Foundation 6. In order to track any changes to the theme I've set up a local Git repository which will later be pushed to GitHub for maintaining the template. Let's call this `repo1`.

Additionally I would like to make my Hugo theme available for others. Let's call this `repo2`.

I have some trouble understanding a possible workflow. Here is what I have in mind:

1. Make changes to the Zurb template and commit them to `repo1`.
2. The Foundation CLI will compile the template to the `dist/` folder.
3. The recompiled content is "promoted" to update the Hugo theme in `repo2`.
4. Additionally the final GitHub pages site is updated with the new Hugo theme.

I habe some trouble puttings this into words but maybe you get the basic idea.

Are there any recommended workflow and setups for developing and publishing a Foundation template in combination with Hugo and GitHub pages?